# Editing Collections with GWT Editors and RequestFactory

Tags: gwt, requestfactory, objectify, gwt-editors

See the [orignal question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7043760/using-gwt-editors-with-a-complex-usecase) for context.

Additional Context:

- Objectify-Appengine is used for persistence.
- `FormProxy` and `QuestionProxy` are of type EntityProxy
- `QuestionDataProxy` and its subtypes are of type `ValueProxy`
- All Editors implement `HasRequestContext`, and in the case of `QuestionData` subtype Editors, `HasRequestContext.setContext()` is called explicitly from the parent.

The first problem has to do with Collections, and [the second has to do with Polymorphic types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7043760/using-gwt-editors-with-a-complex-usecase). I'm not sure if the problem is with the way I'm using Editors or RequestFactory. Since the data isn't present in the RPC payload we can rule out the persistence setup.

### Problem

Values for QuestionProxy are all null in RPC request (if QuestionProxy is newly created, ok otherwise)

### Question

What is the correct way to add / remove `Questions` from the form. What is the sequence of calling create, edit, update methods for `Question`, `Form`, and `QuestionData` while using Editors.

---

### Current Solutions

The add question functionality (in the activity):

```
@Override
public void addQuestion(final QuestionEditor questionEditor) {
    final QuestionProxy proxy = theOneAndOnlyOneContextForEditing.create(QuestionProxy.class);
    final QuestionRequest dpr = theOneAndOnlyOneContextForEditing.append(clientFactory.getRequestFactory()
            .qestionRequest());
    dpr.updateQuestion(proxy);
    questionListEditor.asEditor().getList().add(proxy);
}
```

To remove a question I mark a flag in the question, which will remove it from the list on the server, and delete it. (hack) This only works for questions which have already been saved.

Comment: What's the relationship between `Form` and `Question` ?