# GWT heterogenous lists in editors framework

Tags: java, gwt, gwt-editors

There's a class hierarchy like this:

```
interface Item {
}

interface ItemType1 extends Item {
  String getItemType1Data();
}

interface ItemType2 extends Item {
  String getItemType2Data();
}
```

I have a `List` of `Item` objects that I'd like to display in UI (view only). Is it possible with GWT editors framework? (Please no advices related with my class hierarchy - like moving `getData()` to `Item`)

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=6719 and [Using GWT Editors with a complex usecase](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7043760/116472) (FYI, BobV is the creator of the editor framework)