# GWT ListEditor with polymorphic types - impossible to update

Tags: gwt, polymorphism, gwt-editors

My problem is almost the same as this one :
[ListEditor with polymorphic types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11448082/listeditor-with-polymorphic-types)
Thomas had a good answer, but it is not enough for me.

I want to display list of objects that could be differents, so each editor could be displayed differently.
It almost work, except that I could not find the issue : it is impossible to get the current value and save it.
(i think the setValue method must be called automatically, but i have to call it myself)

Here is some of the code :

ShapeListEditor :

```
public class ShapeListEditor extends VerticalLayoutContainer implements IsEditor<ListEditor<ShapeProxy, ShapeEditorWrapper>> {
public class ESource extends EditorSource<ShapeEditorWrapper> {

    @Override
    public ShapeEditorWrapper create(int index) {
        ShapeEditorWrapper subEditor = new ShapeEditorWrapper(index);
        subEditor.setLayoutData(new VerticalLayoutData(1, -1, new Margins(20, 20, 40, 20)));
        insert(subEditor, index);
        return subEditor;
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose(ShapeEditorWrapper subEditor) {
        remove(subEditor);
    }

    @Override
    public void setIndex(ShapeEditorWrapper editor, int index) {
        insert(editor, index);
    }
}

private ListEditor<ShapeProxy, ShapeEditorWrapper> editor = ListEditor.of(new ESource());

@Override
public ListEditor<ShapeProxy, ShapeEditorWrapper> asEditor() {
    return editor;
}
}
```

ShapeEditorWrapper :

```
public class ShapeEditorWrapper extends Composite implements ValueAwareEditor<ShapeProxy> {

private SimplePanel panel = new SimplePanel();

@Path("")
ShapeEditor ShapeEditor;

public ShapeEditorWrapper(int index) {
    super();
    initWidget(panel);
}


@Override
public void setValue(ShapeProxy value) {
    if (ShapeEditor == null) {
        if (value == null) {

        } else if (value.getShapeType() == ShapeTypeEnum.SQUARE) {
            ShapeEditor = new ShapeSquareEditor();
            ShapeEditor.setValue(value);
            panel.setWidget(ShapeEditor);
        } else if (value.getShapeType() == ShapeTypeEnum.TRIANGLE) {
            ShapeEditor = new ShapeTriangleEditor();
            panel.setWidget(ShapeEditor);
        } 
    } 

}
}
```

ShapeEditor :

```
public class ShapeEditor extends VerticalLayoutContainer implements ValueAwareEditor<ShapeProxy> {

public ShapeEditor() {
    super();
}

@Override
public void setValue(ShapeProxy value) {
}

@Override
public void setDelegate(EditorDelegate<ShapeProxy> delegate) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void flush() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onPropertyChange(String... paths) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

}
```

ShapeTriangleEditor and ShapeSquareEditor have the same properties, but i don't want to have the same display. This classes override setValue(),  create and displays fields, which appear with good values. However, if I change a value, no modification will be detected.

Can anyone tell me what i missed?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. As a suggestion, try this:

**1. In ShapeEditorWrapper**

*It seems you missed setting the value for ShapeTypeEnum.TRIANGLE.*

```
@Override
public void setValue(ShapeProxy value) {
    if (shapeEditor == null) {
        ...
        } else if (value.getShapeType() == ShapeTypeEnum.TRIANGLE) {
            ...
            ShapeEditor.setValue(value); // ===> It seems you forgot this.
            ...
        } 
    } 
}
```

*Flush ShapeEditor whenever the wrapper is flushed.*

```
@Override
public void flush ()
{
    shapeEditor.flush();
}
```

**2. In ShapeEditor, ShapeTriangleEditor and ShapeSquareEditor**

*Assure setValue() actually updates a bean and, if necessary, initialize any of your widgets with the bean values.*

```
private ShapeProxy shape;
@Override
public void setValue(ShapeProxy value) {
    this.shape = value
    // intialize your widget fields here.
}
```

*Flush the widgets values back to the bean. The Editor framework should take care of the rest for you.*

```
@Override
public void flush ()
{
    //Flush your widget values to the proxy
    shape.setXXX(...);
    //...
}
```

I hope it works for you. It did for me!