# How must one use a ListEditor as a child of another Editor?

Tags: gwt, gxt, gwt-editors

I am using GWT 2.5.0

My intent was to create an editor hierarchy which binds to a `ParentBean` object. The `ParentBean` contains a `List<Group>`, and the `Group` bean has a `List<ChildBean>` and `List<Group>`. From the Editor tutorials I have found, it seemed simple enough to create an editor which contains a ListEditor as one of its sub-editors. But the parent editor never seems to properly initialize the sub ListEditor.

Here is an explanation of how I attempted to do this.

From the code below, I created a `ParentBeanEditor` which is composed of one other editor, `GroupListEditor`. 
The `GroupListEditor` implements `IsEditor<ListEditor<Group, GroupEditor>>`.
Then, the `GroupEditor` contains a `GroupListEditor` subeditor and a `ChildBeanEditor`.

I initialized the `ParentBeanEditor` with a `ParentBean` which contained a list of `Group` objects, but no `GroupEditor` was ever constructed for any of the `Group` objects. 
I put break points in the `EditorSource<GroupEditor>.create(int)` method to verify that `GroupEditor`s were being created for each `Group` in the `ParentBean`, but the break point was never hit (the ListEditor was not constructing editors).

I expected that the `GroupListEditor` would be initialized since it was a subeditor of `ParentBeanEditor`. Neither the list nor the editor chain was set in the `GroupListEditor`. I tried to set the list of the `GroupListEditor` subeditor directly in `ParentBeanEditor` by having it extend `ValueAwareEditor<ParentBean>`. Doing this, the break point I mentioned above was hit, and the `GroupListEditor` tried to attach a `GroupEditor` to the editor chain. But the editor chain was never set, and a NPE is thrown in `ListEditorWrapper` line 95.

## Example

Here is the example where the `GroupListEditor` is not initializing as expected. The `EditorChain` is never set, and this results in a NPE being thrown in `ListEditorWrapper` line 95.

### Data Model

```
public interface ParentBean {
    ...
    List<Group> getGroups();
}

public interface Group {
    ...
    List<ChildBean> getChildBeans();
    List<Group> getGroups();
}

public interface ChildBean {
    // ChildType is an enum
    ChildType getChildType();
}
```

### Editors

The ParentBean Editor

```
public class ParentBeanEditor extends Composite implements ValueAwareEditor<ParentBean> {

    interface ParentBeanEditorUiBinder extends UiBinder<Widget, ParentBeanEditor> {
    }

    private static ParentBeanEditorUiBinder BINDER = GWT.create(ParentBeanEditorUiBinder.class);

    @Path("groups")
    @UiField
    GroupListEditor groupsEditor;

    public ParentBeanEditor() {
        initWidget(BINDER.createAndBindUi(this));
    }

    @Override
    public void setDelegate(EditorDelegate<ParentBean> delegate) {}

    @Override
    public void flush() {}

    @Override
    public void onPropertyChange(String... paths) {}

    @Override
    public void setValue(ParentBean value) {

        groupsEditor.asEditor().setValue(value.getGroups());
    }
}
```

GroupListEditor

```
public class GroupListEditor extends Composite implements IsEditor<ListEditor<Group, GroupEditor>>{

    interface GroupListEditorUiBinder extends UiBinder<VerticalLayoutContainer, TemplateGroupListEditor> {
    }

    private static GroupListEditorUiBinder BINDER = GWT.create(GroupListEditorUiBinder.class);

    private class GroupEditorSource extends EditorSource<GroupEditor> {

        private final GroupListEditor GroupListEditor;

        public GroupEditorSource(GroupListEditor GroupListEditor) {
            this.GroupListEditor = GroupListEditor;
        }

        @Override
        public GroupEditor create(int index) {
            GroupEditor subEditor = new GroupEditor();
            GroupListEditor.getGroupsContainer().insert(subEditor, index);
            return subEditor;
        }

        @Override
        public void dispose(GroupEditor subEditor){
            subEditor.removeFromParent();
        }

        @Override
        public void setIndex(GroupEditor editor, int index){
            GroupListEditor.getGroupsContainer().insert(editor, index);
        }

    }

    private final ListEditor<Group, GroupEditor> editor = ListEditor.of(new GroupEditorSource(this));

    @UiField
    VerticalLayoutContainer groupsContainer;

    public GroupListEditor() {
       initWidget(BINDER.createAndBindUi(this));
    }

    public InsertResizeContainer getGroupsContainer() {
        return groupsContainer;
    }

    @Override
    public ListEditor<Group, GroupEditor> asEditor() {
        return editor;
    }
}
```

GroupEditor

```
public class GroupEditor extends Composite implements ValueAwareEditor<Group> {

    interface GroupEditorUiBinder extends UiBinder<Widget, GroupEditor> {}

    private static GroupEditorUiBinder BINDER = GWT.create(GroupEditorUiBinder.class);

    @Ignore
    @UiField
    FieldSet groupField;

    @UiField
    @Path("childBeans")
    ChildBeanListEditor childBeansEditor;

    @UiField
    @Path("groups")
    GroupListEditor groupsEditor;

    public GroupEditor() {
        initWidget(BINDER.createAndBindUi(this));
    }

    @Override
    public void setDelegate(EditorDelegate<Group> delegate) {}

    @Override
    public void flush() { }

    @Override
    public void onPropertyChange(String... paths) {}

    @Override
    public void setValue(Group value) {
        // When the value is set, update the FieldSet header text
        groupField.setHeadingText(value.getLabel());
        groupsEditor.asEditor().setValue(value.getGroups());
        childBeansEditor.asEditor().setValue(value.getChildBeans());
    }
}
```

The `ChildBeanListEditor` will be using the polymorphic editor methodology mention [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7043760/using-gwt-editors-with-a-complex-usecase). Meaning that a specific leafeditor is attached to the editor chain based off the value of the `ChildBean.getType()` enum. However, I am not showing that code since I am unable to get the `GroupListEditor` to properly initialize.

Comment: Could you share your code? It should really be as simple as it seemed in the first place.

Comment: Done. It is scrubbed a little bit, and some parts are left out per my explanation at the bottom.

Comment: And what's the problem exactly? What did you expect that didn't happen? (or didn't expect and which happened) Let's also put the ValueAwareEditor apart as it's an attempt at fixing that problem you didn't actually describe.

Comment: The group list editor is not getting the editor chain. 
I get an NPE in `ListEditorWrapper` line 95.
I'll revise the question to be more specific. Mea culpa.

Comment: That was a little ambiguous :( It should now state what I was trying to do, how I intended to do it, what I expected would happen, and what did not happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two concerns about your code:

Why is `ParentBeanEditor.setValue` feeding data to its child? It appears from this that this was a way to work around the fact that the `GroupListEditor` was not getting data. This should not be necessary, and may be causing your NPE by wiring up a subeditor before it is time.

Then, assuming this, it seems to follow that the `GroupListEditor` isn't getting data *or* a chain. The lack of these suggests that the Editor Framework isn't aware of it. All the basic wiring looks correct, except for one thing: Where is your EditorDriver?

If you are trying to use the editor framework by just invoking `parentBeanEditor.setValue` and do not have a driver, you are missing most of the key features of this tool. You should be able to ask the driver to do this work for you, and not not to call your own setValue methods throughout the tree.

A quick test - try breaking something in such a way that shouldn't compile. This would include changing the `@Path` annotation to something like `@Path("doesnt.exist")`, and trying to run the app. You should get a rebind error, as there is no such path. If you do not get this, you definitely need to be creating and user a driver.

First, try driver itself:

It isn't quite clear from your code what kind of models you are using, so I'll assume that the `SimpleBeanEditorDriver` will suffice for you - the other main option is the `RequestFactoryEditorDriver`, but it isn't actually necessary to use the `RequestFactoryEditorDriver` even if you use RequestFactory.

The Driver is generic on two things: The bean type you intend to edit, and the editor type that will be responsible for it. It uses these generic arguments to traverse both objects and generate code required to bind the data. Yours will likely look like this:

```
public interface Driver extends 
        SimpleBeanEditorDriver<ParentBean, ParentBeanEditor> { }
```

We declare these just like `UiBinder` interfaces - just enough details to let the code generator look around and wire up essentials. Now that we have the type, we create an instance. This might be created in your view, but may still be owned and controlled by some presenter logic. Note that this is *not* like uibinder - we cannot keep a static instance, since each one is wired directly to a specific editor instance.

Two steps here - create the driver, and initialize it to a given editor instance (and all sub-editors, which will be automatic):

```
ParentBeanEditor editor = ...;
Driver driver = GWT.create(Driver.class);
driver.initialize(editor);
```

Next we bind data by passing it to the driver - it is its responsibility to pass sub-objects to each sub-editor's setValue method, as well as wiring up the editor chain required by the ListEditor.

```
driver.edit(parentInstance);
```

Now the user can view or edit the object, as your application requirement works. When editing is complete (say they click the Save button), we can flush all changes from the editors back into the instance (and note that we are still using the same driver instance, still holding that specific editor instance):

```
ParentBean instance = driver.flush();
```

Note that we also could have just invoked `driver.flush()` and reused the earlier reference to `parentInstance` - its the same thing.

Assuming this has all made sense so far, there is some cleanup that can be done - ParentBeanEditor isn't really using the ValueAwareEditor methods, so they can be removed:

```
public class ParentBeanEditor extends Composite implements Editor<ParentBean> {

    interface ParentBeanEditorUiBinder extends UiBinder<Widget, ParentBeanEditor> {
    }

    private static ParentBeanEditorUiBinder BINDER = GWT.create(ParentBeanEditorUiBinder.class);

    @Path("groups")
    @UiField
    GroupListEditor groupsEditor;

    public ParentBeanEditor() {
        initWidget(BINDER.createAndBindUi(this));
    }
}
```

Observe that we still implement `Editor<ParentBean>` - this allows the driver generics to make sense, and declares that we have fields that might themselves be sub-editors to be wired up. Also: it turns out that the `@Path` annotation here is unnecessary - any field/method with the same name as the property (`getGroups()`/`setGroups()` ==> `groups`) or the name of the property plus 'Editor' (`groupsEditor`). If the editor contains a field that is an editor but doesn't map to a property in the bean, you'll get an error. If you actually did this on purpose (say, a text box for searching, not for data entry), you can tag it with `@Ignore`.

Comment: I was trying to illustrate the editor hierarchy I was putting together from the highest point. I (somewhat) intentionally left out the part with the editor driver, because I assumed it was somewhat obvious/straight forward from the [Editors Dev Guide](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiEditors). 
Everything else you've written makes perfect sense. I started out with implementing Editor<ParentBean>, but as you observed, tried using ValueAwareEditor to try and force things through.
It seems apparent that I must go back and clear my assumptions. :)

Comment: Sorry - only can go off of what I have. That said - consider making a local Driver that works with just the little pieces to be sure it works - you might have a `private` or `@Ignore` somewhere preventing the driver stuff from walking the full tree.

Comment: I made a weird assumption :) Using the driver as you've described works. But what I had was an interface which extended Editor<ParentBean>, and ParentBeanEditor extended that interface. Then I had my driver set to use the interface instead of ParentBeanEditor, but initialized with a ParentBeanEditor. I just assumed that since my ParentBeanEditor implemented that interface, the driver would have no problem. This is why it was not working for me. Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes - and that cannot work, since when the driver inspects the `Editor` type (i.e. '`Editor`'), it finds no subeditors, so it does nothing. This make some tasks tricky, like breaking out the driver from the view - I find the best solution is just to have the view expose a `SimpleBeanEditorDriver<T, ?>` so the presenter can manipulate it without creating it.