# Dynamic form with binding in GXT

Tags: forms, gwt, binding, gxt

What would be the best approach to implement a form with a variable number of text fields? I'm thinking something like this:

```
textField1 (removeButton)
textField2 (removeButton)
textField3 (removeButton)

addNewTextFieldButton
```

I would like this to bind to a list of strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I achieved this with an editable grid with a single column and buttons to add/delete rows.

This component is very well integrated with GWT Editor framework so you can bind your grid to a list of objects using a [ListStoreEditor](http://docs.sencha.com/gxt/3/com/sencha/gxt/data/client/editor/ListStoreEditor.html)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Would it be possible for you to share some code? I'm new to GWT.

Comment: Worked it out by myself. Thanks, anyway.

Comment: This is probably a more elegant solution anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

The best approach would be to use the [GWT Editor framework](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiEditors). GXT's fields are very well integrated with the Editor framework.

Here is a very rough example of how you might approach this problem.

You would start by creating one Editor for the thing you are wanting to bind to. In your case, I think a composite which contains a `TextField` (which is bound to the string) and a button. The button won't actually bind to anything, but you will provide a way for something which uses this class to register a `SelectHandler` against it. Let's call this editor `SubEditor`.

Once you create a UI component which is designed to bind to one string, you will next create a `ListEditor<String, SubEditor>` which will bind to a `List<String>` which will compose a view, consisting of one `SubEditor` per each `String` in the bound list.

You don't *really* need to create the `SubEditor`, as you could construct something as simple as what you want within your ListEditor's `EditorSource` class (read through the tutorials on `ListEditors`).

Again, I want to emphasize the this is a *ROUGH* example on how to get started. I hope there is enough information here for you to fill in the pieces.

The following SO question has helped me out a lot:
[Using GWT Editors with a complex usecase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7043760/using-gwt-editors-with-a-complex-usecase)

Comment: I went for the grid solution, turned out to be more suitable in my case. Thanks for your response.